# Showing a sequence does not converge to a limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

so ot very familiar with the coding part.

Question: Does this sequence converge to a limit in $R$, if so what limit?

$x_n$=$(-1)^n (\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2-1})$

My claim: Does not converge to a limit.

My justification: Take the limit of this sub sequence $(x_{2n})$ and take the limit of $(x_{2n-1})$, since the limits do not equal each other then the sequence $x_n$ does not have a limit.

Is this correct? Are there any other methods of doing this? Any faster methods? 
Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct...assuming you know that theorem: if a (real or complex, say) sequence converges then any subsequence converges and to the very same limit as the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your method is correct.

The odd subsequence converges to $-\frac12$ and the even subsequence converges to $\frac12$. Hence it doesn't converge.

Comment: Thank you, do you know any other methods? Just want to keep my options open

Comment: You can also show that it is not cauchy. but I think considering odd and even subsequence seems to be very fast.

Comment: Ah, yes that is also another method, thank you!